# C# generics with children classes

Tags: c#

If I define the following hierarchy

```
public interface IShooter
{ // contract... }

public class ClassA : IShooter
{ // implementation... }

public abstract class InputManager<T>
{ // partial implementation... }
```

then

```
ClassA is IShooter
```

evaluates to `true`, but

```
InputManager<ClassA> is InputManager<IShooter>
```

evaluates to `false`. Is there a way to define this hierarchy in a way such that the second statement also evaluates to `true`?

Comment: To get a "why" answer, you'd have to get the attention of someone on the developer team for the language... which makes the question a poor Stack Overflow fit as written. A better question is "what am I supposed to do?" But in this case, it's always been like that and has always been explicitly documented this way... probably because you don't get your desired behavior for free. It's additional work for the compiler that has to be properly thought through, implemented, tested, documented, etc. You're better off thinking of the `<`/`>` as just another character in one single type name.

Comment: Aside from anything else, why have you named it `ClassA` when it's a `struct`? I'd strongly encourage you to consider names carefully, even for sample code like this, as you don't want the name to be distracting. (And in this particular case, it's really important - see my comment on hakim00's answer.)

Comment: I think you'd also have to define that T is at least of type IShooter for it to be true too.

Comment: Think of it this way. By declaring a class as `InputManager<IShooter>`, you are declaring that it can manage any kind of `IShooter`. An `InputManager<ClassA>` on the other hand can only manage types that derive from `ClassA`. So, not the same. Since it can't do all the same things, it does not have an inheritance relationship.

Comment: @GabeRAMturn No. The latter are two completely distinct types without any inheritance or implements relation.

Comment: Thank you all for the input. I have now updated the question incorporating your feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into something similar in the past. The answer has to do with Covariance and Contravariance generics. You can google them for more in depth explanation, but the caveats that are important are that it only works with interfaces, and it also doesn't work with value types (like your struct ClassA, which I changed to a class below). For example, the following will work as you'd want. (tested with LinqPad)

```cs
void Main()
{
    var i = new InputManager<ClassA>();
    (i is IInputManager<IShooter>).Dump();
}

public interface IShooter { }

public class ClassA : IShooter { }

public interface IInputManager<out T> { }

public class InputManager<T> : IInputManager<T> { }
```

Comment: Nice solution! This makes `InputManager<ClassA> is IInputManager<IShooter>` evaluate to `true`. Is there any way to make `InputManager<ClassA> is InputManager<IShooter>` also evaluate to `true`? There is functionality in the `InputManager` class (not the interface) that I would like to have access to.

Comment: No, as far as I know. The only way is with interfaces, and only because the generic on the `IInputManager` has the `out` keywork to specify covariance. This is also why `IEnumerable<>` is so flexible, it uses 'out' for its generic type.